# Installing letsencrypt on FreeBSD has failed

Tags: software-installation, package-management, freebsd, ssl, letsencrypt

I've been able to install letsencrypt on FreeBSD the same I've been doing on Linux I do this:

```
git clone https://github.com/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.git /opt/letsencrypt
cd /opt/letsencrypt
sudo ./letsencrypt-auto certonly -a standalone -d my_website.com
```

That's it. In FreeBSD I cloned it in a different directory, but the 3rd line threw an exception "support of FreeBsd is still very experimental, you should try to download letscrypt yourself and all the dependencies and ..." build it yourself or something like that. And exited. I haven't saved the exact text.

Is there a similar and easy way to install it on FreeBSD 11?

Comment: The full message also says "please ensure you have backups and then run this script again with the --debug flag. Alternatively, you can install OS dependencies yourself and run this script again with --no-bootstrap."  Did you try again with `--debug`?

Comment: Did you try security/py-certbot ( http://www.freshports.org/security/py-certbot )? It's a client to letsencrypt and works me well.